# java.net.UnknownHostException during fetching in crawl(with nutch 1.4)

Tags: fetch, nutch, web-crawler

I have one link with many external link inside it,when the fetching process start, many external link failed with: java.net.UnknownHostException, i use nutch 1.4 and i set the below setting in nutch-site.xml, is this any misconfiguration?

```
 <property>
        <name>parser.timeout</name>
        <value>30</value>       
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>db.fetch.interval.default</name>
        <value>36000</value>       
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>db.ignore.external.links</name>
        <value>false</value>        
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>http.timeout</name>
        <value>30000</value>       
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>db.max.outlinks.per.page</name>
        <value>-1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>db.fetch.interval.max</name>
        <value>7776000</value>        
    </property>
   <property>
        <name>fetcher.threads.fetch</name>
        <value>10</value>  
   </property>
```